# How to convert "2006-04-01 00:00:00.000 +0200" to "2006-04-01"?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am doing some data cleaning in python. I uploaded a dataset and I am trying to clean the date column. I want to visualize the date column with another component. But when I visualize it with the line plot on the x-axis the date displays as 2006-04-01 00:00:00.000 +0200. I need it to display just 2006-04-01. The date column name is "Formatted Date". And the first couple of rows of the "Formatted Date" columns are the followings.

0: 2006-04-01 00:00:00.000 +0200

1: 2006-04-01 01:00:00.000 +0200

2: 2006-04-01 02:00:00.000 +0200

3: 2006-04-01 03:00:00.000 +0200

When I use the line plot for visualizations and use the "Formatted Date" column as the x-axis I just want it to display 2006-04-01. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for this:
`df['date_column'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime_column']).dt.date`

Answer (score 0):

Using string:

```py
df['date_column'] = df['datetime_column'].str[:len('2006-04-01') +1]
```

Using datetime:

```py
from datetime import datetime


dt = datetime.strptime('2006-04-01 00:00:00.000 +0200', "%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

dt.strftime("%y-%m-%d")
```